# How much hard disk space does Unity Desktop use?

Tags: unity

I'm installing Ubuntu Server into a Virtualbox machine on Windows 7, and I want to install the Unity desktop environment. How much hard disk space does it require?

Comment: Have you already installed Ubuntu Server?  Or are you looking at setting up a server then installing the Unity Desktop with it?

Comment: You can find the installed size of any package for any flavor of Ubuntu at http://packages.ubuntu.com granted the installed size may include packages you already have installed which if true would shrink requirements somewhat.

Answer (score 3):

For my Ubuntu 14.04 server, it seems installing Unity would take **566MB** of disk space.

(See bottom)

```
ubuntu@server:~$ sudo apt-get install unity
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  account-plugin-facebook account-plugin-flickr account-plugin-google
  account-plugin-twitter apg appmenu-qt appmenu-qt5 aptdaemon aspell aspell-en
  avahi-daemon avahi-utils bamfdaemon bluez cheese-common compiz compiz-core
  compiz-gnome compiz-plugins-default cracklib-runtime crda cups cups-browsed
  cups-client cups-common cups-core-drivers cups-daemon cups-filters
  cups-filters-core-drivers cups-pk-helper cups-ppdc cups-server-common
  dconf-cli diffstat dnsmasq-base enchant evolution-data-server
  evolution-data-server-common evolution-data-server-online-accounts friends
  friends-dispatcher friends-facebook friends-twitter gcr geoclue
  geoclue-ubuntu-geoip ghostscript gir1.2-accounts-1.0 gir1.2-atk-1.0
  gir1.2-dbusmenu-glib-0.4 gir1.2-dee-1.0 gir1.2-ebook-1.2
  gir1.2-ebookcontacts-1.2 gir1.2-edataserver-1.2 gir1.2-freedesktop
  gir1.2-gdata-0.0 gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0
  gir1.2-goa-1.0 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gir1.2-ibus-1.0 gir1.2-messagingmenu-1.0
  gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0 gir1.2-notify-0.7 gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0
  gir1.2-pango-1.0 gir1.2-signon-1.0 gir1.2-soup-2.4 gir1.2-unity-5.0
  gkbd-capplet glib-networking glib-networking-common glib-networking-services
  gnome-bluetooth gnome-calculator gnome-control-center-shared-data
  gnome-desktop3-data gnome-icon-theme gnome-icon-theme-symbolic gnome-keyring
  gnome-menus gnome-power-manager gnome-screensaver gnome-session-bin
  gnome-settings-daemon-schemas gnome-system-monitor gnome-user-guide
  gnome-user-share gsettings-desktop-schemas gsettings-ubuntu-schemas gsfonts
  gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio gstreamer1.0-clutter gstreamer1.0-plugins-base
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-x gvfs-backends hardening-includes
  hud humanity-icon-theme hwdata ibus ibus-gtk ibus-gtk3 im-config
  indicator-application indicator-appmenu indicator-bluetooth
  indicator-datetime indicator-keyboard indicator-messages indicator-power
  indicator-printers indicator-session indicator-sound iputils-arping iw
  libaa1 libaccount-plugin-1.0-0 libaccount-plugin-generic-oauth
  libaccount-plugin-google libaccounts-glib0 libaccounts-qt5-1
  libappindicator3-1 libapt-pkg-perl libarchive-zip-perl libarchive13
  libasound2-plugins libaspell15 libatkmm-1.6-1 libaudio2 libauthen-sasl-perl
  libautodie-perl libavahi-core7 libavc1394-0 libbamf3-2 libbluetooth3
  libcaca0 libcairomm-1.0-1 libcamel-1.2-45 libcanberra-gtk3-0
  libcanberra-gtk3-module libcanberra-pulse libcdio-cdda1 libcdio-paranoia1
  libcdio13 libcdparanoia0 libcheese-gtk23 libcheese7 libclone-perl
  libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-1.0-common libclutter-gst-2.0-0
  libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libcogl-common libcogl-pango15 libcogl15 libcolumbus1
  libcolumbus1-common libcompizconfig0 libcrack2 libcupscgi1 libcupsfilters1
  libcupsimage2 libcupsmime1 libcupsppdc1 libdaemon0 libdbusmenu-glib4
  libdbusmenu-gtk3-4 libdbusmenu-qt2 libdbusmenu-qt5 libdecoration0
  libdee-1.0-4 libdigest-hmac-perl libdv4 libebackend-1.2-7 libebook-1.2-14
  libebook-contacts-1.2-0 libecal-1.2-16 libedata-book-1.2-20
  libedata-cal-1.2-23 libedataserver-1.2-18 libegl1-mesa libegl1-mesa-drivers
  libelfg0 libemail-valid-perl libenchant1c2a libfftw3-single3
  libfile-basedir-perl libfontembed1 libframe6 libfriends0 libgbm1
  libgcr-ui-3-1 libgdata-common libgdata13 libgee2 libgeis1 libgeoclue0
  libglamor0 libgles2-mesa libglew1.10 libglewmx1.10 libglib2.0-bin
  libglibmm-2.4-1c2a libgnome-bluetooth11 libgnome-desktop-3-7
  libgnome-keyring-common libgnome-keyring0 libgnome-menu-3-0
  libgnomekbd-common libgnomekbd8 libgoa-1.0-0b libgoa-1.0-common libgrail6
  libgs9 libgs9-common libgsettings-qt1 libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0
  libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0 libgstreamer0.10-0 libgtkmm-3.0-1 libgtop2-7
  libgtop2-common libgutenprint2 libgweather-3-6 libgweather-common
  libibus-1.0-5 libical1 libido3-0.1-0 libiec61883-0 libijs-0.35
  libimobiledevice4 libindicator3-7 libio-pty-perl libio-socket-inet6-perl
  libio-socket-ssl-perl libipc-run-perl libipc-system-simple-perl
  libjack-jackd2-0 libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0 libjbig2dec0 libjson-glib-1.0-0
  libjson-glib-1.0-common libldb1 liblightdm-gobject-1-0
  liblist-moreutils-perl liblzo2-2 libmailtools-perl libmbim-glib0
  libmessaging-menu0 libmetacity-private0a libmm-glib0 libmnl0 libmtdev1
  libmtp-common libmtp-runtime libmtp9 libnet-dns-perl libnet-domain-tld-perl
  libnet-ip-perl libnet-libidn-perl libnet-smtp-ssl-perl libnet-ssleay-perl
  libnetfilter-conntrack3 libnettle4 libnl-3-200 libnl-genl-3-200
  libnl-route-3-200 libnm-glib-vpn1 libnm-glib4 libnm-gtk-common libnm-gtk0
  libnm-util2 libnotify4 libnss-mdns libnux-4.0-0 libnux-4.0-common liboauth0
  libopenobex1 libopenvg1-mesa libp11-kit-gnome-keyring libpackagekit-glib2-16
  libpam-gnome-keyring libpango1.0-0 libpangomm-1.4-1 libpangox-1.0-0
  libpangoxft-1.0-0 libperlio-gzip-perl libplist1 libpocketsphinx1
  libprotobuf8 libproxy1 libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulsedsp
  libpwquality-common libpwquality1 libqmi-glib0 libqpdf13 libqt4-dbus
  libqt4-declarative libqt4-network libqt4-script libqt4-sql libqt4-sql-mysql
  libqt4-xml libqt4-xmlpatterns libqt5core5a libqt5dbus5 libqt5gui5
  libqt5network5 libqt5opengl5 libqt5positioning5 libqt5printsupport5
  libqt5qml5 libqt5quick5 libqt5sensors5 libqt5sql5 libqt5sql5-sqlite
  libqt5test5 libqt5webkit5 libqt5widgets5 libqt5xml5 libqtcore4 libqtdbus4
  libqtgui4 libraw1394-11 libreadline5 librest-0.7-0 librsvg2-2
  librsvg2-common libsamplerate0 libshout3 libsignon-extension1
  libsignon-glib1 libsignon-plugins-common1 libsignon-qt5-1 libsmbclient
  libsocket6-perl libsoup-gnome2.4-1 libsoup2.4-1 libspeex1 libspeexdsp1
  libsphinxbase1 libspice-server1 libstartup-notification0
  libsub-identify-perl libsystemd-journal0 libtag1-vanilla libtag1c2a
  libtalloc2 libtelepathy-glib0 libtevent0 libtext-levenshtein-perl libtheora0
  libtimezonemap1 libunity-control-center1 libunity-core-6.0-9
  libunity-gtk2-parser0 libunity-gtk3-parser0 libunity-misc4
  libunity-protocol-private0 libunity-scopes-json-def-desktop libunity9
  libunityvoice1 libupower-glib1 liburi-perl liburl-dispatcher1 libusbmuxd2
  libvisual-0.4-0 libvisual-0.4-plugins libwacom-common libwacom2 libwavpack1
  libwayland-egl1-mesa libwayland-server0 libwbclient0 libwebkitgtk-3.0-0
  libwebkitgtk-3.0-common libwnck-3-0 libwnck-3-common libwnck-common
  libwnck22 libxatracker2 libxcb-icccm4 libxcb-image0 libxcb-keysyms1
  libxcb-randr0 libxcb-render-util0 libxcb-util0 libxcb-xfixes0 libxcb-xkb1
  libxkbcommon-x11-0 libxkbfile1 libxklavier16 libxres1 libxvmc1 libyelp0
  libzeitgeist-1.0-1 libzeitgeist-2.0-0 lightdm lintian metacity-common
  mobile-broadband-provider-info modemmanager mousetweaks nautilus-data
  network-manager network-manager-gnome network-manager-pptp
  network-manager-pptp-gnome notification-daemon nux-tools obex-data-server
  obexd-client p11-kit p11-kit-modules patchutils poppler-data poppler-utils
  pptp-linux printer-driver-gutenprint pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-x11
  pulseaudio-utils python-cairo python-crypto python-cups python-cupshelpers
  python-dbus python-dbus-dev python-gconf python-gi python-gnomekeyring
  python-gobject python-gobject-2 python-gtk2 python-ldb python-libxml2
  python-notify python-samba python-smbc python-talloc python-tdb python-xdg
  python-zeitgeist python3-aptdaemon python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat python3-crypto
  python3-defer python3-feedparser python3-httplib2 python3-lxml
  python3-oauthlib qdbus qpdf qtchooser qtcore4-l10n rtkit samba-common
  samba-common-bin samba-libs session-migration signon-keyring-extension
  signon-plugin-oauth2 signon-ui signond smbclient sphinx-voxforge-hmm-en
  sphinx-voxforge-lm-en system-config-printer-common
  system-config-printer-gnome system-config-printer-udev t1utils
  telepathy-indicator ubuntu-system-service unity-asset-pool
  unity-control-center unity-control-center-signon unity-greeter
  unity-gtk-module-common unity-gtk2-module unity-gtk3-module
  unity-lens-applications unity-lens-files unity-lens-friends unity-lens-music
  unity-lens-photos unity-lens-video unity-scope-audacious
  unity-scope-calculator unity-scope-chromiumbookmarks unity-scope-clementine
  unity-scope-colourlovers unity-scope-devhelp unity-scope-firefoxbookmarks
  unity-scope-gdrive unity-scope-gmusicbrowser unity-scope-gourmet
  unity-scope-guayadeque unity-scope-home unity-scope-manpages
  unity-scope-musicstores unity-scope-musique unity-scope-openclipart
  unity-scope-texdoc unity-scope-tomboy unity-scope-video-remote
  unity-scope-virtualbox unity-scope-yelp unity-scope-zotero
  unity-scopes-master-default unity-scopes-runner unity-services
  unity-settings-daemon unity-voice-service upower usb-modeswitch
  usb-modeswitch-data usbmuxd wireless-regdb wpasupplicant x11-xkb-utils
  xfonts-base xserver-common xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-core
  xserver-xorg-input-all xserver-xorg-input-evdev xserver-xorg-input-mouse
  xserver-xorg-input-synaptics xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse
  xserver-xorg-input-wacom xserver-xorg-video-all xserver-xorg-video-ati
  xserver-xorg-video-cirrus xserver-xorg-video-fbdev
  xserver-xorg-video-glamoregl xserver-xorg-video-intel
  xserver-xorg-video-mach64 xserver-xorg-video-mga
  xserver-xorg-video-modesetting xserver-xorg-video-neomagic
  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-openchrome
  xserver-xorg-video-qxl xserver-xorg-video-r128 xserver-xorg-video-radeon
  xserver-xorg-video-s3 xserver-xorg-video-savage
  xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion xserver-xorg-video-sis
  xserver-xorg-video-sisusb xserver-xorg-video-tdfx xserver-xorg-video-trident
  xserver-xorg-video-vesa xserver-xorg-video-vmware yelp yelp-xsl zeitgeist
  zeitgeist-core zeitgeist-datahub
Suggested packages:
  libqt5core5 aspell-doc spellutils avahi-autoipd bluez-hcidump cups-bsd
  foomatic-db-compressed-ppds foomatic-db printer-driver-hpcups hplip cups-pdf
  xpp evolution evolution-data-server-dbg ghostscript-x hpijs apache2.2-bin
  libapache2-mod-dnssd ibus-clutter ibus-doc ibus-qt4 click zenity
  unity-greeter-session-broadcast lrzip nas libgssapi-perl libdv-bin
  oss-compat libenchant-voikko libfftw3-bin libfftw3-dev glew-utils
  fonts-droid gstreamer-codec-install gnome-codec-install gstreamer0.10-tools
  gstreamer0.10-plugins-base gutenprint-locales jackd2
  libqt4-declarative-folderlistmodel libqt4-declarative-gestures
  libqt4-declarative-particles libqt4-declarative-shaders qt4-qmlviewer
  libqt4-dev libicu48 qt4-qtconfig libraw1394-doc librsvg2-bin speex
  unity-common libwww-perl url-dispatcher binutils-multiarch
  libhtml-parser-perl libtext-template-perl libyaml-perl gnome-control-center
  nautilus network-manager-openconnect-gnome network-manager-openvpn-gnome
  network-manager-vpnc-gnome fonts-japanese-mincho fonts-ipafont-mincho
  fonts-japanese-gothic fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-arphic-ukai
  fonts-arphic-uming fonts-unfonts-core gutenprint-doc pavumeter paman
  pavucontrol paprefs pulseaudio-module-raop pulseaudio-esound-compat
  python-crypto-dbg python-crypto-doc python-dbus-doc python-dbus-dbg
  python-gnome2-doc python-gi-cairo python-gobject-2-dbg python-gtk2-doc
  python3-crypto-dbg python3-lxml-dbg qt4-default qt5-default heimdal-clients
  cifs-utils libcanberra-gtk-module x11-xserver-utils
  lightdm-remote-session-freerdp lightdm-remote-session-uccsconfigure
  remote-login-service audacious clementine gmusicbrowser guayadeque musique
  tomboy metacity x-window-manager comgt wvdial wpagui
  libengine-pkcs11-openssl xfs xserver xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi
  xfonts-scalable gpointing-device-settings touchfreeze xinput firmware-linux
  linux-firmware
Recommended packages:
  indicator-applet indicator-renderer
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  account-plugin-facebook account-plugin-flickr account-plugin-google
  account-plugin-twitter apg appmenu-qt appmenu-qt5 aptdaemon aspell aspell-en
  avahi-daemon avahi-utils bamfdaemon bluez cheese-common compiz compiz-core
  compiz-gnome compiz-plugins-default cracklib-runtime crda cups cups-browsed
  cups-client cups-common cups-core-drivers cups-daemon cups-filters
  cups-filters-core-drivers cups-pk-helper cups-ppdc cups-server-common
  dconf-cli diffstat dnsmasq-base enchant evolution-data-server
  evolution-data-server-common evolution-data-server-online-accounts friends
  friends-dispatcher friends-facebook friends-twitter gcr geoclue
  geoclue-ubuntu-geoip ghostscript gir1.2-accounts-1.0 gir1.2-atk-1.0
  gir1.2-dbusmenu-glib-0.4 gir1.2-dee-1.0 gir1.2-ebook-1.2
  gir1.2-ebookcontacts-1.2 gir1.2-edataserver-1.2 gir1.2-freedesktop
  gir1.2-gdata-0.0 gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0
  gir1.2-goa-1.0 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gir1.2-ibus-1.0 gir1.2-messagingmenu-1.0
  gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0 gir1.2-notify-0.7 gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0
  gir1.2-pango-1.0 gir1.2-signon-1.0 gir1.2-soup-2.4 gir1.2-unity-5.0
  gkbd-capplet glib-networking glib-networking-common glib-networking-services
  gnome-bluetooth gnome-calculator gnome-control-center-shared-data
  gnome-desktop3-data gnome-icon-theme gnome-icon-theme-symbolic gnome-keyring
  gnome-menus gnome-power-manager gnome-screensaver gnome-session-bin
  gnome-settings-daemon-schemas gnome-system-monitor gnome-user-guide
  gnome-user-share gsettings-desktop-schemas gsettings-ubuntu-schemas gsfonts
  gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio gstreamer1.0-clutter gstreamer1.0-plugins-base
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-x gvfs-backends hardening-includes
  hud humanity-icon-theme hwdata ibus ibus-gtk ibus-gtk3 im-config
  indicator-application indicator-appmenu indicator-bluetooth
  indicator-datetime indicator-keyboard indicator-messages indicator-power
  indicator-printers indicator-session indicator-sound iputils-arping iw
  libaa1 libaccount-plugin-1.0-0 libaccount-plugin-generic-oauth
  libaccount-plugin-google libaccounts-glib0 libaccounts-qt5-1
  libappindicator3-1 libapt-pkg-perl libarchive-zip-perl libarchive13
  libasound2-plugins libaspell15 libatkmm-1.6-1 libaudio2 libauthen-sasl-perl
  libautodie-perl libavahi-core7 libavc1394-0 libbamf3-2 libbluetooth3
  libcaca0 libcairomm-1.0-1 libcamel-1.2-45 libcanberra-gtk3-0
  libcanberra-gtk3-module libcanberra-pulse libcdio-cdda1 libcdio-paranoia1
  libcdio13 libcdparanoia0 libcheese-gtk23 libcheese7 libclone-perl
  libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-1.0-common libclutter-gst-2.0-0
  libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libcogl-common libcogl-pango15 libcogl15 libcolumbus1
  libcolumbus1-common libcompizconfig0 libcrack2 libcupscgi1 libcupsfilters1
  libcupsimage2 libcupsmime1 libcupsppdc1 libdaemon0 libdbusmenu-glib4
  libdbusmenu-gtk3-4 libdbusmenu-qt2 libdbusmenu-qt5 libdecoration0
  libdee-1.0-4 libdigest-hmac-perl libdv4 libebackend-1.2-7 libebook-1.2-14
  libebook-contacts-1.2-0 libecal-1.2-16 libedata-book-1.2-20
  libedata-cal-1.2-23 libedataserver-1.2-18 libegl1-mesa libegl1-mesa-drivers
  libelfg0 libemail-valid-perl libenchant1c2a libfftw3-single3
  libfile-basedir-perl libfontembed1 libframe6 libfriends0 libgbm1
  libgcr-ui-3-1 libgdata-common libgdata13 libgee2 libgeis1 libgeoclue0
  libglamor0 libgles2-mesa libglew1.10 libglewmx1.10 libglib2.0-bin
  libglibmm-2.4-1c2a libgnome-bluetooth11 libgnome-desktop-3-7
  libgnome-keyring-common libgnome-keyring0 libgnome-menu-3-0
  libgnomekbd-common libgnomekbd8 libgoa-1.0-0b libgoa-1.0-common libgrail6
  libgs9 libgs9-common libgsettings-qt1 libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0
  libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0 libgstreamer0.10-0 libgtkmm-3.0-1 libgtop2-7
  libgtop2-common libgutenprint2 libgweather-3-6 libgweather-common
  libibus-1.0-5 libical1 libido3-0.1-0 libiec61883-0 libijs-0.35
  libimobiledevice4 libindicator3-7 libio-pty-perl libio-socket-inet6-perl
  libio-socket-ssl-perl libipc-run-perl libipc-system-simple-perl
  libjack-jackd2-0 libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0 libjbig2dec0 libjson-glib-1.0-0
  libjson-glib-1.0-common libldb1 liblightdm-gobject-1-0
  liblist-moreutils-perl liblzo2-2 libmailtools-perl libmbim-glib0
  libmessaging-menu0 libmetacity-private0a libmm-glib0 libmnl0 libmtdev1
  libmtp-common libmtp-runtime libmtp9 libnet-dns-perl libnet-domain-tld-perl
  libnet-ip-perl libnet-libidn-perl libnet-smtp-ssl-perl libnet-ssleay-perl
  libnetfilter-conntrack3 libnettle4 libnl-3-200 libnl-genl-3-200
  libnl-route-3-200 libnm-glib-vpn1 libnm-glib4 libnm-gtk-common libnm-gtk0
  libnm-util2 libnotify4 libnss-mdns libnux-4.0-0 libnux-4.0-common liboauth0
  libopenobex1 libopenvg1-mesa libp11-kit-gnome-keyring libpackagekit-glib2-16
  libpam-gnome-keyring libpango1.0-0 libpangomm-1.4-1 libpangox-1.0-0
  libpangoxft-1.0-0 libperlio-gzip-perl libplist1 libpocketsphinx1
  libprotobuf8 libproxy1 libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulsedsp
  libpwquality-common libpwquality1 libqmi-glib0 libqpdf13 libqt4-dbus
  libqt4-declarative libqt4-network libqt4-script libqt4-sql libqt4-sql-mysql
  libqt4-xml libqt4-xmlpatterns libqt5core5a libqt5dbus5 libqt5gui5
  libqt5network5 libqt5opengl5 libqt5positioning5 libqt5printsupport5
  libqt5qml5 libqt5quick5 libqt5sensors5 libqt5sql5 libqt5sql5-sqlite
  libqt5test5 libqt5webkit5 libqt5widgets5 libqt5xml5 libqtcore4 libqtdbus4
  libqtgui4 libraw1394-11 libreadline5 librest-0.7-0 librsvg2-2
  librsvg2-common libsamplerate0 libshout3 libsignon-extension1
  libsignon-glib1 libsignon-plugins-common1 libsignon-qt5-1 libsmbclient
  libsocket6-perl libsoup-gnome2.4-1 libsoup2.4-1 libspeex1 libspeexdsp1
  libsphinxbase1 libspice-server1 libstartup-notification0
  libsub-identify-perl libsystemd-journal0 libtag1-vanilla libtag1c2a
  libtalloc2 libtelepathy-glib0 libtevent0 libtext-levenshtein-perl libtheora0
  libtimezonemap1 libunity-control-center1 libunity-core-6.0-9
  libunity-gtk2-parser0 libunity-gtk3-parser0 libunity-misc4
  libunity-protocol-private0 libunity-scopes-json-def-desktop libunity9
  libunityvoice1 libupower-glib1 liburi-perl liburl-dispatcher1 libusbmuxd2
  libvisual-0.4-0 libvisual-0.4-plugins libwacom-common libwacom2 libwavpack1
  libwayland-egl1-mesa libwayland-server0 libwbclient0 libwebkitgtk-3.0-0
  libwebkitgtk-3.0-common libwnck-3-0 libwnck-3-common libwnck-common
  libwnck22 libxatracker2 libxcb-icccm4 libxcb-image0 libxcb-keysyms1
  libxcb-randr0 libxcb-render-util0 libxcb-util0 libxcb-xfixes0 libxcb-xkb1
  libxkbcommon-x11-0 libxkbfile1 libxklavier16 libxres1 libxvmc1 libyelp0
  libzeitgeist-1.0-1 libzeitgeist-2.0-0 lightdm lintian metacity-common
  mobile-broadband-provider-info modemmanager mousetweaks nautilus-data
  network-manager network-manager-gnome network-manager-pptp
  network-manager-pptp-gnome notification-daemon nux-tools obex-data-server
  obexd-client p11-kit p11-kit-modules patchutils poppler-data poppler-utils
  pptp-linux printer-driver-gutenprint pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-x11
  pulseaudio-utils python-cairo python-crypto python-cups python-cupshelpers
  python-dbus python-dbus-dev python-gconf python-gi python-gnomekeyring
  python-gobject python-gobject-2 python-gtk2 python-ldb python-libxml2
  python-notify python-samba python-smbc python-talloc python-tdb python-xdg
  python-zeitgeist python3-aptdaemon python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat python3-crypto
  python3-defer python3-feedparser python3-httplib2 python3-lxml
  python3-oauthlib qdbus qpdf qtchooser qtcore4-l10n rtkit samba-common
  samba-common-bin samba-libs session-migration signon-keyring-extension
  signon-plugin-oauth2 signon-ui signond smbclient sphinx-voxforge-hmm-en
  sphinx-voxforge-lm-en system-config-printer-common
  system-config-printer-gnome system-config-printer-udev t1utils
  telepathy-indicator ubuntu-system-service unity unity-asset-pool
  unity-control-center unity-control-center-signon unity-greeter
  unity-gtk-module-common unity-gtk2-module unity-gtk3-module
  unity-lens-applications unity-lens-files unity-lens-friends unity-lens-music
  unity-lens-photos unity-lens-video unity-scope-audacious
  unity-scope-calculator unity-scope-chromiumbookmarks unity-scope-clementine
  unity-scope-colourlovers unity-scope-devhelp unity-scope-firefoxbookmarks
  unity-scope-gdrive unity-scope-gmusicbrowser unity-scope-gourmet
  unity-scope-guayadeque unity-scope-home unity-scope-manpages
  unity-scope-musicstores unity-scope-musique unity-scope-openclipart
  unity-scope-texdoc unity-scope-tomboy unity-scope-video-remote
  unity-scope-virtualbox unity-scope-yelp unity-scope-zotero
  unity-scopes-master-default unity-scopes-runner unity-services
  unity-settings-daemon unity-voice-service upower usb-modeswitch
  usb-modeswitch-data usbmuxd wireless-regdb wpasupplicant x11-xkb-utils
  xfonts-base xserver-common xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-core
  xserver-xorg-input-all xserver-xorg-input-evdev xserver-xorg-input-mouse
  xserver-xorg-input-synaptics xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse
  xserver-xorg-input-wacom xserver-xorg-video-all xserver-xorg-video-ati
  xserver-xorg-video-cirrus xserver-xorg-video-fbdev
  xserver-xorg-video-glamoregl xserver-xorg-video-intel
  xserver-xorg-video-mach64 xserver-xorg-video-mga
  xserver-xorg-video-modesetting xserver-xorg-video-neomagic
  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-openchrome
  xserver-xorg-video-qxl xserver-xorg-video-r128 xserver-xorg-video-radeon
  xserver-xorg-video-s3 xserver-xorg-video-savage
  xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion xserver-xorg-video-sis
  xserver-xorg-video-sisusb xserver-xorg-video-tdfx xserver-xorg-video-trident
  xserver-xorg-video-vesa xserver-xorg-video-vmware yelp yelp-xsl zeitgeist
  zeitgeist-core zeitgeist-datahub
0 upgraded, 563 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 144 MB of archives.
After this operation, 566 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Comment: If you need to save space, you can reduce the number of packages by specifying the `--no-install-suggests` and `--no-install-recommends` flags to `apt-get`.

Answer (score 0):

[Recommended Minimum System Requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) server shows at least **1GB** for CLI. I would recommend more than that for tools installations and other applications that you might need.

I just did an installation of Ubuntu Server, then I installed the Unity Desktop all within a VirtualBox VM.  The total installation came to about **2.3GB** with it all installed.  I set this one up with a dynamic size of 30GB for testing.  I installed Unity without all the extra stuff with the following command for the installation:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop --no-install-suggests --no-install-recommends
```

**NOTE:** I have had an issue with installing the VirtualBox extras as they keep failing about the kernel.  This is a 14.04 installation that I have not upgraded.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: The OP is installing Ubuntu *server*, **not** Ubuntu *desktop*.  OP only wants to know how much disk space the Unity DE *itself* takes. Ubuntu desktop includes a bunch of other software, such as Libreoffice, that server doesn't.

Comment: I'll be happy to reverse the downvote if you revise your answer :)

Comment: I've removed the downvote.